# Open the lightning component at the time of Utility bar loading

Tags: lightning-aura-components, utility-bar

I have binded a lightning component in utility. And I want to open that utility at the time of loading by default. But Lightning init handler not working properly.

Here is my code:

**.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilitybar" />
    Auto Open Utility
</aura:component>
```

**.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var utilityAPI = component.find("utilitybar");
        utilityAPI.openUtility();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to little bit change your init event code. In init event utilityid not retrieved so you should use below code, it should work.

```
 doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    var utilityAPI = component.find("utilitybar");
    utilityAPI.getAllUtilityInfo().then(function (response) {
        if (typeof response !== 'undefined') {
                    utilityAPI.openUtility();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Dhanik,
Thanks for your response. But actually waht happning my init function not calling on loading of the page.

init function in only calling when i am manually opening the activity.

Comment: Have you checked flag ‘Start Automatically‘ for lightning component in utility bar?

Comment: Thanks, Dhanik for help